# what type for this element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

This is an element from an xml file :

```
<note>This is <b>very urgent</b> !</note>
```

For the schema It should say that inbetween the "note" tags there may be placed anything!

This is what I have for the Schema :

```
<xs:element name="note" minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:anyType"></xs:element>
```

For some reason the anytype specifier gives me this error :

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'b'.
```

Even an regex pattern .* won't work. Cause it is seen as sext

Is it possible to make the note tag fit everything?

Even when it has other childelements in it ?

thanx

---

EDIT: For some reason the AnyType is working properly now...I must have made an mistake in Visual Studio!

Problem Solved!

Comment: Is `<b>very urgent</b>` a separate element, or just a string value of the `<note>` element?

Comment: It has to be a string value of the <note>. However...now it it seeing it as an element...:(

Comment: that's because it's not a valid XML.  Values can't contain `<` or `>`.  Is this an XML you are creating or from another application?

Comment: It's from my lector. He wants me to make the scheme for it.

Comment: Well, seems you found something that worked, but still doesn't change the fact that it isn't a valid XML.

Comment: Indeed Bro! You are right. But I can't change the xml file for the assignment. But my problem was also fixed by declaring a complexType and set the Mix atrribute to "true". Now in my note tag it is allowed to have an B tag :p!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an element wildcard, and that would be xsd:any. Since you're trying to "sprinkle" it with text nodes as well, then you have to set the mixed attribute.

```
<xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Correct answer. Just to elaborate: processContents="lax" means that any child elements (such as `<b>`) have to conform to the schema definition with matching element name if there is one, but if there is none, they are taken as valid. The alternatives are "strict" which requires an element declaration for the child elements, and "skip" which ignores any element declaration even if there is one.